# Shortest distance between objects

Tags: javascript, algorithm

let say I have an object such that :

```
let objs = { obj1: [ 0, 10 ], obj2: [ 3, 9 ], obj3: [ 5, 12, 14 ] }
```

Each obj has more than one distance points, but only one should be chosen to combine with other obj's distance point.

I can combine three objects based on the distance points above in 12 ways.

For example, it could become [0,3,5];
In this case , the total distance between three objects would be 5 - 0 which is 5;

Or it can become [10, 9, 5], and the distance is 10 - 5 = 5;

The combination can also be [0, 3, 12] and the distance is 12 - 0 = 12;

What I intend to achieve is to find the shortest combination, which in this case should be [10, 9, 12]; and the distance is 12-9 =3;

So I have thought of performing combinations one by one; I can do nested loop to do that but it would be very inefficient.
What is the most efficient method I can use to achieve this?

Comment: Two minor things: "shortest" is unclear here (shortest runtime?/shortest code?/...) Also - do you know that an O(n) method exists? If not, there might be none and this would be an unfulfillable constraint.

Comment: @schnaader, I have made amendments to my post regarding your question. Let me know if you have issue :)

Comment: Is it just three objects always? How many points do your objects have on average? Which number can grow bigger?

Comment: @Bergi, Right, so there is no limit to the number of objects, and the number of points in each object can be arbitrary too. But let's assume those numbers are fixed as of now.

Comment: Won't the solution be: "foreach box pick the greatest one, then go through the rest of boxes, finding the lowest one, that's greater than initially picked; if there's no greater, disregard", as such - the algorithm will do: 1. 10, 9, quit; 2. 9, 10, 12 - found, 3. 14, 10, quit. Probably need to look both ways (ie. pick lowest one, then go through rest finding the greatest one)

Comment: @eithed OP is trying to find the minimal distance. Your algorithm seems fine for computing the maximum distance.

Comment: @Bergi the maximum would be [0, x, 14] I think, which I don't see in the products :D will have a look at writing a solution once I'm near computer

Comment: @eithed Ah, i guess I have missed "finding the lowest one *which is greater than initially picked*".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could get the cartesian product and then reduce the array by taking the one with the smaller delta of max and min value.

```js
let objects = { obj1: [ 0, 10 ], obj2: [ 3, 9 ], obj3: [ 5, 12, 14 ] },
    data = Object.values(objects),
    cartesian = data.reduce((a, b) => a.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(b.map(w => [].concat(v, w))), [])),
    result = cartesian.reduce((a, b) => Math.max(...a) - Math.min(...a) < Math.max(...b) - Math.min(...b) ? a : b)

console.log(result);
console.log(cartesian.map(a => a.join(' ')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A faster approach uses a sorted array and takes only the last three items of every array in sorted order.

This is a linear search without using a cartesian product.

> ```
> index  values                delta
> -----  --------------------  -----
>    0    0          10 
>    1       3     9
>    2          5       12 14
>        --------                 5
>        --    -----              9
>              --------           5
>                 --------        3 <-- min
>                 ------   --     5
> ```

```js
let objects = { obj1: [ 0, 10 ], obj2: [ 3, 9 ], obj3: [ 5, 12, 14 ] },
    data = Object
        .values(objects)
        .map((a, i) => a.map(v => [v, i]))
        .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b))
        .sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0] || a[1] - b[1]),
    parts = [undefined, undefined, undefined],
    result,
    i;

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    parts[data[i][1]] = data[i][0];
    if (parts.some(v => v === undefined)) continue;
    if (!result || Math.max(...parts) - Math.min(...parts) < Math.max(...result) - Math.min(...result)) {
        result = parts.slice();
    }
}

console.log(result);
console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Constructing the cartesian product is just what the OP means by "nested loops".

Comment: I think your second approach uses the idea detailed in @Maras' answer - you should upvote it!

Answer (score 4):

For each value v in obj o create pair (v, o), then sort all of the pairs by the first element of pair. It takes O(n log n)

Now you want to choose some consecutive elements from the sorted sequence that at least one of every o is inside. You can choose the best answer in O(n log n) (or O(n) using hash map)

Start with choosing the smallest prefix of the sequence that satisfies the condition. Make two pointers, the start of your consecutive chosen elements and the end.

Start = 1, end = x (where x is the smallest value that every object is inside the chosen set)

Then try increasing start (by deleting first element of chosen subsequence) and increase end as long as it's necessary.
Take the minimum of the differences between end and start values, it's your answer.

As I said, to keep track if all objects are inside create a map/hash map, where you can store for each object o the amount of it in your chosen sequence.
When you increase start you have to decrease the amount of some of the objects inside the subsequence. Then you should increase end until every object o occur nonzero amount of times in the chosen subsequence. (To obtain O(n log n) complexity store how many objects has a value of 0. When you increase any, decrease the counter, when you decrease any object's amount to 0, increase it)

The result is always correct, no heuristics is used.

Comment: You don't even need a (hash) map for the objects - you can just give them indices and store your counts in an array.

Comment: Sometimes it's not that simple, but in overall yes, as long as you can easily enumerate objects you can just use an array

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's anything better than nested/recursive loops, in the worst case you will still need to examine all combinations. However, I think applying the [branch-and-bound algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound) will give a good optimisation as it will prune branches with not-so-good distances early - also taking advantage of the fact that your points per objects are sorted, so you can prune multiple choices at once.

Actually, for each object we can prune to just 2 choices that are nearest-below and nearest-above the interval selected so far. I would therefore estimate a worst-case complexity of `O(k * (2+log k)n)` (given `n` objects with on average `k` already-sorted points), not the `O(kn)` of the naive enumeration.

Admittedly, this is worse than the `O(kn log(kn) + kn²)` of Nina's second approach or the `O(kn log(kn))` of Maras' algorithm - which can be further improved to `O(kn log n)` by using a [n-way merge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-way_merge_algorithm) on already-sorted lists.

Comment: This is basically what I wanted to achieve with my A* algorithm suggestion, but A* is not fitting as its heuristic is useless here (we can't estimate further costs).

Comment: @גלעדברקן Yes, I guess I was wrong - I've felt like that since Maras posted their answer. Still I won't delete my answer as I think branch-and-bound has its merits.